# How to finish one operation in Node.js if some limit time is exceeded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Consider that we want to perform some operation which takes some time to complete in Node.js, say `doHeavyWork()`. What we usually do is that we pass a callback function like that:

```
doHeavyWork(params, callbackFunction);
```

Now, I want to stablish one limit time for the operation to complete. What I want is that if the uptime of that operation exceeds the limit time, the function terminates and informs the callback that the limit time was exceeded.

How can this be accomplished in Node.js?

Comment: Use a promise instead of a callback. Start the process, and resolve when it's complete. Start a timer and reject when the timer's complete. Whichever finishes first wins.

Comment: Is the `doHeavyWork()` function synchronous code (like computer intensive stuff) or asychronous code (like file or networking)?  If synchronous, it's a lot more difficult without modifying the function itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 the actual concrete situation which lead me to this problem was with `doHeavyWork` performing asynchronous operation (a HTTP request). When I asked I thought there was a way to tackle the two kinds of situations the same way, that's why I didn't specify it in the question. I didn't think being synchronous would make things that more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You'd think this is possible with a simple callback, but I'm going to illustrate a problem for you

```js
function doHeavyWork(params, callback) {
  // set the timeout
  var timeout = setTimeout(callback, 5000, Error('timeout'))
  
  // some debug message
  console.log('Please wait...')
  
  // begin heavy work
  // we sill simulate heavy work with setTimeout here
  setTimeout(function() {
    
    // if the function completed in time, clear the timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    
    // callback without error
    callback(null, 'done')
  }, 3000)
}

// check to see it work
doHeavyWork('some params', function(err, res) {
  if (err)
    throw error
  else
    console.log(res)
})
```

Now watch what happens if you change the `3000` to a value that exceeds the `5000` ms timeout — for example, try `10000`. You will see that the `callback` **is called twice**. This is not good! And not trivial to fix unless you want to clutter up your function with a ton of rubbish.

If we use a Promise, we can fix this quite easily tho

```js
function doHeavyWork(params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // set the timeout
    var timeout = setTimeout(reject, 5000, Error('timeout'))

    // some debug message
    console.log('Please wait...')

    // begin heavy work
    // we sill simulate heavy work with setTimeout here
    setTimeout(function() {

      // if the function completed in time, clear the timeout
      clearTimeout(timeout)

      // callback without error
      resolve('done')
    }, 3000)
  })
}

// check to see it work
doHeavyWork('some params').then(
  function(res) { console.log(res) },
  function(err) { console.log(err.message) }
)
```

Now watch what happens if you change the `3000` to `10000` again. The Promise "callback" will only be called once

---

Lastly, this code can even be improved just a little bit more using `Promise.race`. `Promise.race` will return a new Promise that resolves or rejects as soon as one of the input Promises resolves or rejects. This is perfect for our use case.

Most crucially, notice how the timeout logic is not coupled with `doHeavyWork`. This keeps your functions clean and nicely organized.

```js
function doHeavyWork(params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // some debug message
    console.log('Please wait...')

    // begin heavy work
    // we sill simulate heavy work with setTimeout here
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'done')
  })
}

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(reject, ms, Error('timeout'))
  })
}

// using Promise.race
Promise.race([
  timeout(5000),
  doHeavyWork('some params')
]).then(
  function(res) { console.log(res) },
  function(err) { console.log(err.message) }
)
```

In the code example above, change the timeout value of `5000` to something shorter like `1000` to see what the error looks like